# Replace characters outside a given charset with U+FFFD?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-unicode

I have to accept user input in utf-8 and feed it to a system that only accepts ISO-8859-15. **I'd like to convert all non-ISO-8859-15 characters in a user-supplied unicode string to U+FFFD** so I could present the problematic characters to the user. What's the easiest* way to accomplish this?

I'm using Python 2.7.

*) With an arbitrary definition of "the easiest" :)

Comment: Did you mean *latin-1*?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik No, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15  - but that's actually not important here. The same question would apply anyway.

Comment: Python doesn't seem to have a latin-9.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik True, it's called 'ios-8859-15' in Python. I was lazy when writing the question. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def is_latin_9(c):
    try:
        c.encode('iso-8859-15')
        return True
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False

def replace_non_latin_9(s):
    return ''.join(c if is_latin_9(c) else u'\ufffd' for c in s)
```

Comment: Thanks, does the trick. Quite verbose and probably awfully slow esp. when the input has lots of non-latin-9 chars - but in practice this will not be a problem for me. I was hoping there was a more built-in way, but maybe there isn't. Probably one faster way would be to make a set of unicode codepoints that belong to latin-9, but that would mean even more code.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to do this faster than O(n). You do need to go over every character. As for verbosity, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: (Quite academic by now, but it's fun to think these out. :)) Surely it's O(n). I'm not familiar with Python's internals, but I assume that a function call and a try-catch for each character isn't probably a cheap solution.